# Is there any way to compare text generated with OCR API with another text view on click of button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, ocr

I am working on a college project and in that one module uses Ocr api from google to read text. I want to compare the text generated from Ocr which is in a text view with another text view on click of button which i am not able to do.

I have already tried to compare the two textviews using :

if (quest_text.getText().toString().equals(textView.getText().toString();))

here the quest_text is one textView and textView is for Ocr text.

```
    Resources res = getResources();
    final String[] OcrQuestion = res.getStringArray(R.array.ocr_questions);

    quest_text.setText(String.format(OcrQuestion[0]));

    final String ab= textView.getText().toString();

    ocr_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (quest_text.getText().toString().equals(ab))
            {
                score+=10;
            }
            ImageScore.setText(String.format("%d",score));
            quest_text.setText(String.format(OcrQuestion[1]));
        }
    });
```

The result which i want is when the text generated by Ocr in a textView matches which text in another textView ("quest_text") on click of button the score will increase by 10 and new text will be fetched from String Array in textView ("quest_text").

But the text matching is not taking place only the next element from String Array.

Comment: Did you try printing both the strings? Are they actually equal?

Comment: Actually the issue is i am not able to figure out what is the actually output from Ocr. I can see the text from ocr but i am not understanding is it only text or something more

Comment: You can check if its a string or something else by printing it. If it prints without using toString() or String.valueOf(var) then its a string.

Comment: public void run() {
                     StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                                for (int i=0;i<items.size();++i)
                                {
                                    TextBlock item=items.valueAt(i);
                                    stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                       }
                                textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());                                        this is the function i am using to get text from Ocr.

Comment: Actually i think the Ocr output is not a string. So now what should i do to compare the two text Views ?

Comment: I dont know on what basis you are saying that the later one is not a string. Please confirm it first.

Comment: And for comparing different type of variables you need to set a standard of similarity which you would want to check.

Comment: @Wijdan The text from the String builder is a string. I checked by using the method you told me. But the text in the text view , i have to use toString. So now i am stuck , I am not able to compare the two text.

Comment: If you can convert the later string by to String then you can compare it already. What do you actually want?

Comment: I want to compare text from string builder to the text view and if they match the score will increase.

Comment: @Wijdan Hey my problem is solved. I made a string and stored value from the String builder and then compared with the Text view. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Great. Good luck.